# Values are null when I wanna edit DB in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with my project in ASP.NET Model-View-Controller.

I have an application "Guestbook". I can successfully create guests, but I cannot edit them.

Look: 
1. I start application - all ok
2. I create a guest - all ok (guest has all the entered data)
3. I click "edit" - all ok
4. I see new window. All fields on the screen have correct data, but I have a breakpoint in edit function and I see that all variables are null.

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Guestbook.Models
{
    public class Guest
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "name", ResourceType=typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
              ErrorMessageResourceName = "nameRequired")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
                          ErrorMessageResourceName = "nameLong")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "surname", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
              ErrorMessageResourceName = "surnameRequired")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
                          ErrorMessageResourceName = "surnameLong")]
        public string surname { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "firm", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
              ErrorMessageResourceName = "firmRequired")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
                          ErrorMessageResourceName = "firmLong")]
        public string firm { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "toWhom", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
              ErrorMessageResourceName = "toWhomRequired")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
                          ErrorMessageResourceName = "toWhomLong")]
        public string toWhom { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "permitNumber", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "permitRequired")]
        [Range(0, 10000, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
                       ErrorMessageResourceName = "permitRange")]
        public int permitNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "magazine", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
              ErrorMessageResourceName = "magazineRequired")]
        public bool magazine { get; set; } 


        [Display(Name = "entranceTime", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? entranceTime { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "entranceTimeTime", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        public string entranceTimeTime { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "exitDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? exitDate { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "exitTime", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        public string exitTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class GuestDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Guestbook.Models;

namespace Guestbook.Controllers
{
    public class GuestsController : BaseController
    {
        private GuestDBContext db = new GuestDBContext();

        // GET: Guests
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //Sortowanie po nazwisku.
            var guests = from s in db.Guests select s;
            guests = guests.OrderBy(s => s.surname);
            return View(guests.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Guests/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Guest guest = db.Guests.Find(id);
            if (guest == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(guest);
        }

        // GET: Guests/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Guests/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,name,surname,firm,toWhom,permitNumber,magazine,entranceTime,entranceTimeTime,exitDate,exitTime")] Guest guest)
        {
            guest.entranceTime = DateTime.Today;
            guest.exitDate = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            string format = "HH:mm:ss";
            guest.entranceTimeTime = dt.ToString(format);
            guest.exitTime = dt.ToString(format);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Guests.Add(guest);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(guest);
        }

        // GET: Guests/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Guest guest = db.Guests.Find(id);
            if (guest == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(guest);
        }

        // POST: Guests/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "exitDate,exitTime")] Guest g)
        {

            g.exitDate = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            string format = "HH:mm:ss";
            g.exitTime = dt.ToString(format);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(g).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(g).Property(gg => gg.name).IsModified = false;
                db.Entry(g).Property(gg => gg.surname).IsModified = false;
                db.Entry(g).Property(gg => gg.firm).IsModified = false;
                db.Entry(g).Property(gg => gg.permitNumber).IsModified = false;
                db.Entry(g).Property(gg => gg.magazine).IsModified = false;
                db.Entry(g).Property(gg => gg.toWhom).IsModified = false;
                db.Entry(g).Property(gg => gg.entranceTime).IsModified = false;
                db.Entry(g).Property(gg => gg.entranceTimeTime).IsModified = false;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(g);
        }

        // GET: Guests/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Guest guest = db.Guests.Find(id);
            if (guest == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(guest);
        }

        // POST: Guests/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Guest guest = db.Guests.Find(id);
            db.Guests.Remove(guest);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Guestbook.Models.Guest

@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Resources.exitGuest;
}

<h2>@Resources.exitGuest</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firm, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.firm, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <b>@Resources.leftOk</b>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value=@Resources.y class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="button" value=@Resources.cancel onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("","guests")'" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Firstly you haven't created any controls except one hidden input so thats the only thing which will post back. Secondly you specify `[Bind(Include = "exitDate,exitTime")]` so even the ID you posted back is ignored so of course each property is `null` or is default value.

Comment: @DavidG - `exitDate` and `exitTime` are null when the edit function starts.    
    
@StephenMuecke         
Ad 1. Should I write `@Html.HiddenFor()` for all variables?        
    
Ad 2. I tried to include all variables and no variables. It doesn't work.

Comment: Not much point adding only hidden inputs (its an edit form so you need textboxes or other controls to edit your properties). Just forget the `[Bind(Include-...)]` bit. All properties will bind by default (so long as you post them back!) and if you do use it, then you should be using a view model anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly in your view you are only outputting a single form variable which is the ID parameter. All of the other model properties are being displayed only. You either need to output them as, for example, `EditorFor` or `HiddenFor` to get them posted back.

Secondly in your `Edit` method, the method signature is this:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "exitDate,exitTime")] Guest g)
```

The [`Bind` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) is telling the MVC model binder to only bind the `exitDate` and `exitTime` properties so everything else will show as `null`. You can either remove the attribute:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guest g)
```

Or add in the other properties that you require to be passed in:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "exitDate,exitTime,name,surname,etc...")] Guest g)
```

So if you combine those two problems you will see that even the `ID` property isn't getting passed through and everything is null.

Comment: Thanks. It works! I changed `DisplayFor` on `EditorFor` for parameters that I want to display on the screen and I add `HiddenFor` for others in the view! I also remove the `Bind` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(...
```

instead of

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(....
```

That way the view will then pass them to the controller 'edit' HttpPost ActionResult after form submission.

---

The

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(...
```

Is only used for *outputting the model to the screen*. It does not, however, allow them to be edited in this way (Hence use the [TextBoxFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) or [EditorFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx) instead)

---

I'm not too sure if you want the '`exitDate`' and `exitTime` to be manually edited or not, but if you do, then you will need to add them to your view, as well as including them in your Binding Property after adding them to your model.

If you do, then using something like:

```
(Guest  guest)
```

instead of binding the data

Should include a binding for that.

Comment: Thanks for help. Unfortunately I cannot vote up, because Vote Up requires 15 reputation, but your answer helped me too. :)

Comment: np glad you got sorted :)